# Why does the ternary operator in VB.NET accept a Nullable Boolean?

Tags: vb.net, ternary-operator

The following compiles in VB.NET (with Option Strict On) and outputs `False`:

```
Dim b As Boolean? = Nothing
Dim myString = If(b, "True", "False")
```

Why does that work?

- [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) clearly states that the three-argument version of `If` requires a `Boolean` as the first parameter:

  > *argument1* Required. Boolean. Determines which of the other arguments to evaluate and return.
- and there is no implicit conversion from `Boolean?` to `Boolean`:

  ```
  Dim b1 As Boolean? = Nothing
  Dim b2 As Boolean = b1   ' Fails with the following error:
                           '   Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions
                           '   from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'.
  ```

So, why does this work? Is it a bug (or "hidden feature") in the compiler or is it a bug in the documentation and `Boolean?` is actually a valid type for the first argument of `If(a, b, c)`?

PS: In C#, `b ? x : y` does *not* compile if `b` is of type `bool?`.

---

**EDIT**: I've [reported this issue to Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693530). Someone from MS has replied and confirmed that the documentation will be updated to include the `Boolean?` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two "why's". Why does it and why did they do it that way. I can answer the first, the second is Microsoft's.

If you inspect the code generated from VB.Net using Reflector you'll see this:

```
Dim b As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Nothing
Dim myString As String = IIf(b.GetValueOrDefault, "True", "False")
```

Or C#:

```
bool? b = null;
string myString = b.GetValueOrDefault() ? "True" : "False";
```

So the compiler itself is inserting the `GetValueOrDefault` for the `Nullable(of T)`

Comment: Does it really use IIF?  (note two I's)?

Comment: Good catch. My Reflector was set to .Net 2.0 which didn't have the VB `IF` ternary operator. Updating to 4.0 makes it `IF` instead of `IFF`. Obviously this is Reflector trying to reconstruct VB.Net from IL. The actual IL command is `brtrue.s` which is "branch if true" which is what ternary operations are usually converted to.

Answer (score 2):

Docos states this:

> An If operator that is called with three arguments works like an IIf
>   function except that it uses short-circuit evaluation. An IIf function
>   always evaluates all three of its arguments, whereas an If operator
>   that has three arguments evaluates only two of them. The first If
>   argument is evaluated and the result is cast as a Boolean value, True
>   or False.

It evaluates and then Casts.

**EDIT1**

The interesting part is that, at runtime, the cast did not throw an exception.

Comment: `The first If argument is evaluated and the result is cast as a Boolean value`... nicely spotted! Interestingly, it doesn't seem to be true: `If(0, 1, 2)` throws `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'Boolean'.`, so the first argument is not *always* cast to a Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Keep ildasm.exe handy for questions like this.  The compiler uses Nullable(Of T).GetValueOrDefault().  The official language spec does not forbid this.  Nor is it otherwise illuminating about it, this is not unusual.

```
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   b
  IL_0003:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
  IL_0009:  ldloca.s   b
  IL_000b:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
  IL_0010:  brtrue.s   IL_0019
  etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nullables, you should always use the .HasValue property rather than just refering to the nullable. VB has a legacy of using the following syntax when checking to see if an object has been instantiated or not:

```
If Foo Then
  ' Is instantiated
End If
```

As a result, your example allows for evaulation of the ternary If. I recommend "fixing" your code to be a bit more explicit in this case:

```
Dim b As Boolean? = Nothing 
Dim myString = If(b.HasValue, "True", "False")
```

Alternatively, instead of using the ternary If, why not just rewrite it as:

```
Dim myString = b.GetValueOrDefault(False).ToString()
```